# Change only the clicked button to an new one

Tags: php, jquery

I have a button inside a table row which changes with a boolean value.

```
<tr id="<?php echo $zeile['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $zeile['id'] ?>" class="task">
<td >
<form method="POST" action="main.php" value="<?php echo $zeile['id']; ?>">
<?php if ($done == true): ?>
    button type="submit" name="checkbtn" id='<?php echo $zeile['id']; ?>' >                                          
       Check
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $zeile['id']; ?>">
<?php else: ?>  
   <button type="submit" name="uncheckbtn" id='<?php echo $zeile['id']; ?>'>                                          
      UnCheck
   </button> 
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $zeile['id']; ?>">  
<?php endif ?>     


</form>

</td>
```

The boolean value is change after the button is clicked here for ('checkbtn' and 'uncheckbtn')

```
$done = true;

if(isset($_POST['checkbtn'])){
    *sqlvariables*
    $done = false;
    *sql*
}
```

with my jquery I want that I can click anywhere on the row to do a button click:

```
$(".table tr").on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlighttask');
        $(this).find('button[name="checkbtn"]').click();
    });
```

The Problem is that every button changes to unchecked if I click on one row.

I think that I need to work with id's, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You already have click event handler on tr so no need to use `closest`, just use `find` button

```
$(".table tr").on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlighttask');
        $(this).find('button[name="checkbtn"]').click();
    });
```

Comment: Thats true, thanks. But it still changes every button.

Comment: This should click only button inside the clicked row. You button type is submit so it  should be submitting whole form. is that the case, can you share button click event handler code or share what exactly is happening?

Comment: It clicks the right button, thats true, but through the boolean every button in every row is changing to unchecked, not only the clicked one.

Comment: yah, that is the reason i want to see the click event handler of button where you are changing the boolean so that i can tell you the issue and its solution

Comment: The `if(isset($_POST['checkbtn'])){...` is my button click event. Isn't it?

Comment: `*sqlvariables*
    $done = false;
    *sql*` is not enough to understand how you are changing boolean and showing unchecked button

Comment: But thats everything I have if the button is clicked boolean sets from true to false. and inside the form of the button there is an if/else, which changes the button based on the boolean.